# jQuery code performance improvement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a field and when I paste some content in it, the content gets validated and added line by line to another hidden field. My content can be a number of mobile number separated by new line and when you paste them in to the visible field, each line gets validated and added to another hidden field which is used to pass the value to the backend.

e.g.

```
12345
54321
34567
```

They way I use to add the value to the hidden field can be seen in the following piece of code:

```
$('#recipients').val($('#recipients').val().length <= 0 ? output.join("\n") : $('#recipients').val() + "\n" + output.join("\n"));
```

in above code 'output' is a line (a number) from the content the user paste and the recipients is the hidden field.

This line gets called as many as my content lines. But when I check the performance this line takes a lot of cpu load (when the number of lines are too high) and creates a lag on doing the job (browser hanging).

So can this line of code be rewritten in a more efficient way?

Thanks,

Comment: Cache your selector, that should improve performance and make your code cleaner.

Comment: Can u pls be more specific?

Comment: @ComeRun What he means is that instead of creating a jq object everytime first set var `$elm = $('#recipients');` and then onwards use `$elm`

Comment: cool got it tnx. any other comments on how to improve the performance?

Comment: The problem is the join() it will be slow for large values. Not much you can do about that, the other "improvements" are milliseconds of improvement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to cache the result of a selector in a variable:

```
var $recip = $("#recipients");
var $recipval = $recip.val();
var new_out = output.join("\n");
$recip.val($recipval.length == 0 ? new_out : $recipval + "\n" + new_out);
```

You can also bypass jQuery, to get a little more boost:

```
var recip = $("#recipients")[0];
var recipval = recip.value;
var new_out = output.join("\n");
recip.value = recipval.length == 0 ? new_out : recipval + "\n" + new_out;
```

`new_out` doesn't affect performance, it just makes the code easier to understand.

Comment: I'd avoid `val()` altogether and use `value`.

Comment: @Barmar can you please explain why [0] would help? is it because of the less element look up?

Comment: @ComeRun he is bypassing an extra jquery wrapper and directly dealing with DOM element. Also remember to cache `recip = $("#recipients")[0];` out side the function so you don't want to do it over and again... for every paste

Comment: It's just so you can use the native `.value` instead of calling the jQuery `.val()` method.

Comment: If you are going to do that, might as well just use getElementById. None of this is going to help, the problem is join() and you are not going to speed that up.

Comment: @epascarello Considered that, but decided I like the brevity of jQuery selector syntax.

Comment: Basically what OP is doing is `el.value += '\n'+ output.join('\n')`. I would just do that and then replace the first `\n` with nothing. Probably not the best performance but the cleanest approach IMO.

Comment: @PSL If I put the recip = $("#recipients")[0]; outside of my function I receive an error that recip is not defined when the function is called! no?

Comment: I'd have to see exactly how you laid things out, but it sounds like you didn't put it into a different function's scope, rather than a containing scope.

Comment: @Barmar I believe I need to include recip = $("#recipients")[0] inside the function since everytime the function gets called, the value of the field could be different so it needs to be updated everytime.

Comment: The value changes, but the element doesn't, unless you replace the element dynamically.

Comment: So: `recip.value = (recipval == '' ? '' : recipval + "\n") + output.join('\n');` I'll bet the join part runs faster than the jQuery selector (because it has to make a jQuery object too).